# A criterion for rational singularities in mixed characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, singularity-theory

Let $R$ be a mixed characteristic discrete valuation ring with perfect residue field and $f:X \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ a flat proper morphism.

> If the generic fibre of $f$ is smooth and the special fibre has $F$-injective singularities then does $X$ have rational singularities?

I take the definition of rational singularities to be as in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02269) of Kovacs. One could also just assume that the generic fibre has rational singularities, but the above is enough for my needs.

If this is not true, are there any other criteria of a similar flavour? I am happy to assume that $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay (though not Gorenstein, and I also do not want to assume that the special fibre is normal).

The reason for thinking that the question might have a positive answer is a result of Fedder and Watanabe (Proposition 2.13 of "A characterization of F-Regularity in terms of F-Purity") proving a pure characteristic $p$ version of this result and a result of Schwede
(Theorem 5.1 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4125)) proving a pure characteristic zero version.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an open question   I don't even think we know it is Cohen-Macaulay.  There are some things in the paper of Sato-Takagi https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.03721 (see Theorem 3.7) that are quite close, but it's more in the F-pure / log terminal direction (ie, you said we didn't want to assume Gorenstein).  If the special fiber has F-rational singularities, then everything is ok.  Btw, you can just assume that the generic fiber has rational singularities (smoothness is not needed), this is done in a paper of myself and Sándor Kovács.

Comment: @KarlSchwede: Thanks a lot for your comments and the reference. Does the question appear anywhere in the literature? Also, as I wrote above, I am willing to assume that $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay, but I am not sure that this helps. (I had seen your paper with Kovacs which is why I made the remark after the question.)

Comment: It's definitely a question that Linquan Ma and I talked about, but I don't think it made it into the literature.  I think we were looking at a stronger question of whether X is BCM-Rational.  The strongest results in this direction are due to Sato-Takagi, and I think they looked at related questions too, ie what happens when the special fiber is char p F-injective, but it doesn't seem to be asked in their paper.

Comment: @KarlSchwede: OK, thanks!